# Filter objects in array by any value within another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, and an array of values that I need to filter the objects by. I can remove duplicates from the array, but trying to figure out how to filter the objects with ids that have a match (or using `startsWith()`) to filter objects with an id that starts with a given value.

In the end, the object with id "F11v6" should be removed from the resulting array.

```js
let blacklistedComponents = ["F11", "U30"];
let components = [
  { id: "F11v6", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "U30v3", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CH11", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CT12", type: "true" },
  { id: "U03v5", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CT12", type: "true" }
];
console.log(components.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.id===v.id))===i));
```

Comment: please add the result. why should `'U30v3'` stay?

Comment: That was an oversight. It should be removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look to the blalisted items an check if `id` is in the list.

```js
const
    blacklistedComponents = ["F11", "U30"],
    components = [{ id: "F11v6", type: "unknown" }, { id: "U30v3", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CH11", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CT12", type: "true" }, { id: "U03v5", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CT12", type: "true" }],
    result = components
        .filter(({ id }) => !blacklistedComponents.some(v => id.includes(v)))
        .filter((s => ({ id }) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A single loop approach

```js
const
    blacklistedComponents = ["F11", "U30"],
    components = [{ id: "F11v6", type: "unknown" }, { id: "U30v3", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CH11", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CT12", type: "true" }, { id: "U03v5", type: "unknown" }, { id: "CT12", type: "true" }],
    result = components.filter(
        (s => ({ id }) =>
            !blacklistedComponents.some(v => id.includes(v)) &&
            !s.has(id) &&
            s.add(id)
        )(new Set)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't contain the duplicate entry removal.

Comment: please see edit with a additional check.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter those elements that match the ones from the disallowed list using `!.some()`. Then apply your filter to get rid of the duplicates, e.g.:

```js
const disallowed = ['F11', 'U30'];
const components = [
    {id: 'F11v6', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'U30v3', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CH11', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CT12', type: 'true'},
    {id: 'U03v5', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CT12', type: 'true'}
];

const filtered = components
    .filter((v) => !disallowed.some(e => v.id.startsWith(e)))
    .filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.id===v.id))===i);
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't contain the duplicate entry removal.

Comment: Right, updated the answer (using your duplicate check). You can simply apply multiple filter operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if you just wanted to remove elements that start with a black listed item, or if ones that contain it anywhere.

Used composition to show how you could do either, and deconstruction to extract the relevant field as the parameter for each filter.

```js
const disallowed = ['F11', 'U30'];
const components = [
    {id: 'F11v6', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'U30v3', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CH11', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CT12', type: 'true'},
    {id: 'U03v5', type: 'unknown'},
    {id: 'CT12', type: 'true'}
];

let blackListFilterContains = ( {id} ) => !disallowed.some(testValue => id.includes(testValue));
let blackListFilterStartsWith = ( {id} ) => !disallowed.some(testValue => id.startsWith(testValue));
let uniqueFilter = (value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index;

let result = components.filter(blackListFilterContains);
console.log(result)
result = result.filter(uniqueFilter);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let blacklistedComponents = ["F11", "U30"]
let components = [
  { id: "F11v6", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "U30v3", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CH11", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CT12", type: "true" },
  { id: "U03v5", type: "unknown" },
  { id: "CT12", type: "true" }
]
const idAllowed = id => !blacklistedComponents.some(c=>id.startsWith(c))
const result = [...new Set(components.map(({id})=>id))] // unique ids
  .filter(idAllowed) // retain only non-blacklisted ids
  .map(id=>components.find(i=>id===i.id)) // correlate to components

console.log(result)
```